# How can Mockito verify with conditions?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

So I'd like to verify a method by Mockito.

```
Subject subject = loadSubject(); 
Teacher teacher = loadTeacher();
Mockito.verify( exam ).createExam( subject , teacher );
```

But I'd like to verify this method if this condition is true:

```
subject.name.equals("Math") && subject.complexity == 10
```

So how can I add conditions to Mockito verify?

Comment: Assuming that you have control over `loadSubject()` , the Subject object needs to be created with name as "Math" and complexity as 10 followed by verify invocation.

Comment: Can't you just wrap the verify() call in an if() block?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wrote the things not too clearly.
Now I found the solution, it is:

private static class Matcher extends ArgumentMatcher {
      public boolean matches(Subject sub) {
          return sub.getName().equals("Math") && sub.getComplexity() == 10; 
      }
   }

Answer (score 2):

according to the documentation of Mockito, there is no way to specify a condition
http://goo.gl/23fYi

From the small piece of code you have posted, I guess you want to do a conditional call, Mockito then registers all the interaction as stated in the doc

> Once created, mock will remember all interactions. Then you can selectively verify whatever interaction you are interested in.

So

```
Exam mockedExam = mock(Exam.class);
mockedExam.createExam(subject, teacher);
verify(mockedExam).createExam(subject, teacher);
```

somewhere you have to insert the conditional block, for instance

```
@Test
public void testExamCreation() throws Exception {
    if(subject.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Math") && subject.getComplexity() == 10) {
        mockedExam.createExam(subject, teacher);
    }
    verify(mockedExam).createExam(subject, teacher);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wrote the things not too clearly.
Now I found the solution, it is:

private static class Matcher extends ArgumentMatcher {
      public boolean matches(Subject sub) {
          return sub.getName().equals("Math") && sub.getComplexity() == 10; 
      }
   }

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue:
Mockito **ArgumentCaptor** is probably what you are looking for, here is a nice example:
https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor

Comment: This is a great answer. Please do include a small code sample (the [answering guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) say "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline." Also might be nice to link to the [official documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#captors)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I found that you can conditionally verify. Im my case, I wanted to verify a method was called on my mock/spy ONLY if another method (real implementation) was also called. I was able to do this by using a custom doAnswer that sets a boolean and then calls the real method. In the below example, verify that `doSkip` is called IF `readName` is called.

```
final BsonDocumentReader reader = spy(new BsonDocumentReader(document));
final AtomicBoolean readNameCalled = new AtomicBoolean(false);

doAnswer(invocation -> {
   readNameCalled.set(true);
   return invocation.callRealMethod();
}).when(reader).readName();

if (readNameCalled.get()) {
   verify(reader).skipValue();
}
```